# Have to reinstall FiraCode everytime before I start Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio I'm using the monospace font [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode). I've configured Visual Studio 2019 Community (with Resharper and latest updates) to use this font and after installing it it works fine. The font also works with other editors/IDE's (Visual Studio Code, PyCharm). But after every reboot of my machine, I have to reinstall FiraCode again to get the font working in VS. However, in the other mentioned editors/IDE's, the font works without having to reinstall FiraCode.

The FiraCode font is present in the font list in the options of VS and selected. After a reinstall, the FiraCode font is still selected but now it's also visible as used font in the editor.

I would like it if I didn't have to reinstall the font every time (since I forget it regularly. This means close VS, install font, open VS, wait for Resharper to finish (again)). Anyone with a solution? Workaround is somehow reinstall the font automatically at every boot.

Comment: Did you remember to first check, and ask on, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html?

Comment: No I didn't, I'll try that one first.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this issue? I'm experiencing the same issue and it's really annoying.

Comment: @KerimEmurla Unfortunately no solution was found. Had contact with someone from the Microsoft team and they tried to help me, but were unable to reproduce the problem I'm having (we ran out of options to try to reproduce the problem on their machine). So it's unsolved. I've just configured the automatic installation of the font you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue for couple of days and I thought it was really annoying to install the font over and over again after each restart of my machine, so I decided to automate the process.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/deploymentguys/adding-and-removing-fonts-with-windows-powershell) post by `Michael Murgolo`, which installs a font using a Powershell script.

Using the Powershell script all I had to do is create a .bat file that contains the following lines:

```
@echo off
PowerShell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
PowerShell -command "& '%~dp0Add-Font.ps1' -path '%~dp0FiraCode-Regular.ttf'"
```

*You need the specify the path to where the font is located, if it's not located in the same folder as the Powershell script.*

After having a .bat file that installs the font I had to make sure it gets run on every startup. For that purpose I used the `Task Scheduler` and created a new task that has the 
`"Run with the highest privileges"` checkbox checked.

After all those steps the `FiraCode` font gets installed automatically on every startup and it's ready to use when you open your Visual Studio.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this alternative, but couldn't find it. This will save me some time.